# Is it possible to access package members using JNI?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm having an issue getting objects from my imports using JNI. Is it possible? For example, say I have this in my java file:

```java
import foo.Bar;

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(){
        Bar.runMethod();
    }
}
```

Can I reference "Bar" using JNI without changing the Java code? I've only been able to create a new "Bar" object, which isn't what I want to do.

edit: to expand on this a bit, the runMethod() does something like this:

```
public class Bar{
    public static void runMethod(){
        Bar inst = new Bar();
        ...more code...
    }
}
```

So now there's an instance of Bar floating around that I'm not sure how to access using JNI. If bar has things like togglebuttons, radio buttons, etc, I can't use JNI to manipulate them since I can't get a jobject that references it. Is there anything I can do, or do I have to resort to editing the Java file? (I don't maintain the code, so it would be a last resort)

Comment: JNI can access any method of any object, including private methods of Java classes. This question however doesn't provide enough concrete detail for us to understand the context well enough to help you.

Comment: Are you saving any references to inst, or can you call a JNI method with it as a parameter?  If it's just a local variable, there's no sane way to get the reference. Stated another way, this isn't a problem about JNI, it's a problem of obtaining a reference to the allocated Bar object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JNI can access any method of any object, including private methods of Java classes. This question however doesn't provide enough concrete detail for us to understand the context well enough to help you.

The Oracle reference is a little obtuse, but if you provide a code sample from the JNI side, we can likely demystify it a bit for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp15982

Comment: Alright, I suppose I will have to mess around with the java source to get the desired functionality. I was hoping there would be some way to go into the scope of a method or find a currently running instance of a class, but I suppose not.

I've edited the code a bit to put the field declaration at the top level, but I am having NullPointerExceptions when I try to access its fields in JNI...If I can't figure out why I'll post another question tomorrow.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, or your title, but you can certainly pass a Bar instance to a native method, or Bar.class, or find Bar.class from inside it.

Comment: Hey, I expanded a bit more on my question in an edit. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: As I said, you can pass a Bar instance to a native method. If that doesn't answer your question it still isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bar{
public static void runMethod(){
    Bar inst = new Bar();
    ...more code...
}
```

The instance of Bar named inst within the method "runMethod" no longer exists when the function completes, unless it is stored under a static class variable later in your "more code" section, so there wouldn't be an instance for you to reference.

JNI is only going to give you access to class members and methods, most certainly not local method variables.